# HTML5 pushState() in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, wordpress, pushstate

I am trying to implement pushstate for a wordpress site and having some real troublke

I've tried using these

When I use
http://html5.gingerhost.com/ = I get error

```
GET http://wwww.mydomain.com/content.php?format=json

404 Not Found
        487ms   
jquery.min.js (line 4)

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.mydomain.com/content.php?format=json"
```

These 2 methods shows me entire page! rather than specified section

1. http://tinywall.info/2012/02/22/change-browser-url-without-page-reload-refresh-with-ajax-request-using-javascript-html5-history-api-php-jquery-like-facebook-github-navigation-menu/
2. http://www.franckmaurin.com/how-to-use-html5-history-with-wordpress-jquery/

Am I missing something here related to wordpress may be?

my navigation looks like this

```
    <ol class="primary-nav">  
        <li class="page_item"><a href="http://www.mydomain.com/charities">/&nbsp;Charities</a></li>
        <li class="page_item"><a href="http://www.mydomain.com/contact">/&nbsp;Contact</a></li>
        <li class="page_item"><a href="http://www.mydomain.com/join-us">/&nbsp;Join us</a></li>
        <li class="page_item"><a href="http://www.mydomain.com/news">/&nbsp;News</a></li>
        <li class="page_item"><a href="http://www.mydomain.com/who-we-are">/&nbsp;Who we are</a></li>
    </ol>
```

Comment: what browser are you in?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it with this method

http://www.franckmaurin.com/how-to-use-html5-history-with-wordpress-jquery/

Issue was ajax request was requesting the entire html as oppose to specific data

So I changed

```
 $(this).html(data).fadeTo('fast', 1);
```

to

```
 $(this).html($(data).find('#main').html()).fadeTo('fast', 1);
```

or

```
  var requiredElement = $(data).find('#main').html()

  $(this).html(requiredElement).fadeTo('fast', 1);
```